# Skylake Integrated Graphics not working on 16.04 Server

Tags: 16.04, drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, i915

I am trying to install 16.04 Ubuntu Server on a machine with a Gigabyte H270 chipset motherobard and an i5-6400. Server installation runs smoothly without any issues.

On the first boot though the screen turns blank after trying to load VESA VGA (can't remember the exact line). I could boot into a nomodeset shell. In there I installed xorg and gnome as well as gnome system tools and gnome app install (as per manual we use for slightly different machines). Another reboot yielded the same black screen and now even the nomodeset shell doesn't work as the screen flickers with 2 second periods. After installing openssh-server via the root recovery shell I can log in via putty from another machine on the network.

The next information is partly based on a similar topic here:
[Skylake Integrated graphics not working on 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725092/skylake-integrated-graphics-not-working-on-15-10)

Via putty I tried to figure out what's wrong. dmesg | grep -i i915 gives me a bunch of stuff. Warnings and 1 error. Interesting stuff:

```
[    5.557010] [drm:vlv_enable_pll.isra.85 [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* DPLL 0 failed to lock
[    7.305174] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
```

Also lshw -enable pci -class display yields:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

So the graphic driver doesn't load and the display isn't claimed. Might that be because I am in a terminal only putty session? inxi -b tells me:

```
System:    Host: <PC Name> Kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Console: tty 0 Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Gigabyte product: H270-HD3 v: Default string serial: Default string
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: H270-HD3-CF v: x.x serial: Default string
           Bios: American Megatrends v: F1 date: 11/22/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-6400 (-MCP-) speed/max: 3208/3300 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 driver: N/A tty size: 182x62 Advanced Data: N/A for root out of X
Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (0.9% used)
Info:      Processes: 169 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 246.6/3870.7MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5
           Client: Shell (sudo) inxi: 2.2.35
```

No display driver :(

dpkg -l xserver-xorg-video-intel:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                    Version                  Architecture             Description
+++-=======================================-========================-========================-====================================================================================
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                2:2.99.917+git20160325-1 amd64                    X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

ls -l /sys/class/drm:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 card0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 card0-DP-1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 card0-HDMI-A-1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 card0-HDMI-A-2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 card0-HDMI-A-3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 controlD64 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/controlD64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  8 09:36 renderD128 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/renderD128
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  8 09:36 version
```

S

I am not sure what's wrong. The X Server doesn't seem to run at all, as there is no log in /var/log/ or ~/.local/share/xorg/.

Not sure what's going wrong really ... anyone care to enlighten me how to debug this?